# Why am I getting no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I 'm trying to use letsencrypt SSL certificate. For that I followed the instructions found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-8#step-2-obtain-an-ssl-certificate).

I just keep getting the message on nginx error.log when I try to access the website in a browser:
`no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking`.

I ended up with the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name admin.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name admin.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3010;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

When I try access the website I'm redirected to https with the message unable to access website.

Comment: What exactly were you doing when you got the message, and where does that message appear?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The message appears on nginx error.log when I try to access the website in a browser. The browser displays site unavailable.

Comment: Is that your complete nginx configuration?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen To this domain yes.

Comment: Other domains' configuration files might be relevant too. Did you use `http://example.com` when opening the site or `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Neither. In this case the domain starts with admin so: admin.example.com. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57608/discussion-between-tero-kilkanen-and-belyid).